# PHPSpreadsheet - How do create a extra tab?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I create in my php code a excel file with one tab and give it a name.
The code what i use is this.:

```
// CREATE PHPSPREADSHEET OBJECT
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;

// CREATE A NEW SPREADSHEET + POPULATE DATA
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('Batch');
```

But how do i create a second tab with another name?

[solved]

```
// CREATE A NEW SPREADSHEET + POPULATE DATA
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('Batch');
// Add some data
$spreadsheet->createSheet();
// Add some data
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1) ->setCellValue('A1', 'world!');
// Rename worksheet
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('URL Removed');
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Answer (score 25):

You can add an extra tab like this:

```php
$spreadsheet->createSheet();
// Zero based, so set the second tab as active sheet
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Second tab');
```

If you like, [you can read more here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/#adding-a-new-worksheet).

Comment: missing end line comma after (1), but +1 thanks for the useful answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing out! Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way

```
//at the beginning of the code
            use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;


            $myWorkSheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'Extra Tab');
            $spreadsheet->addSheet($myWorkSheet, 0);

            $sheetIndex = $spreadsheet->getIndex(
                $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Extra Tab')
            );

            $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
```

For more information [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/#adding-a-new-worksheet)