Writing to a multi-sheet excel file using phpSpreadsheet
Is there a way to write to a specific sheet in an excel multi-sheet file using PhpSpreadsheet without the sheets in said excel file being wiped out?
The write function in phpSpreadsheet always creates a new file thus wiping out my original file. Is this normal?
Below snippet always creates a new file:
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
  $writer->save("mymultisheet-spreadsheet.xlsx");


Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736333/phpspreadsheet-how-do-create-a-extra-tab is what you need?

You need to load the file you want to modify.
